# Elfinder On dblClcik

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-office, elfinder

Am using Elfinder Plugin in my website and what i need when i double click on the file, to open it on another windows with  [Office Web Viewer](http://officewebviewer.com).

On the Select Even, i Did it like below:

```
 $('#elfinder').elfinder({ 
                url : "php/connector.minimal.php?id='.$id.'&level='.$level.'&office='.$office.'",
                    lang : "ar",
                handlers    : {
                    select : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
                        var selected = event.data.selected;
                        if(selected.length > 0){
                           var file = elfinderInstance.file(selected[0]);
                           window.open("https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://e-lawyer.co/elfinder/files/"+elfinderInstance.path(selected[0])+"&embedded=true", "_blank");
                        }
                    }
                }
});
```

I need to do the same thing but On Double Click Event

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `getFileCallback` of client configuration option.

```javascript
$('#elfinder').elfinder({ 
    url : "php/connector.minimal.php?id='.$id.'&level='.$level.'&office='.$office.'",
    lang : "ar",
    getFileCallback : function(file, fm) {
        var url = fm.convAbsUrl(fm.url(file.hash));
        window.open('https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&embedded=true', '_blank');
    }
});
```

Comment: @MohammadKassab If the answer solved your issue, be sure to accept it. Take a moment to check [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is something you should do on all answers that solve your quesitons. Thanks